# How to interpret spectral projections?

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a Borel set and $\chi_\Omega$ its indicator function. If $A$ is a bounded self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space, we use the Borel functional calculus to define the spectral projector $\chi_\Omega(A)$.

If we let $\Omega = \{\lambda\}$, a single point set, then according to this answer (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/146475/823800) $\chi_{\{\lambda\}}$ is interpreted as the operator which projects onto the eigenspace of $\lambda$ if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue and zero if $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue.

I have two questions about these spectral projections:

1. What happens if $\lambda$ is in the spectrum but is not an eigenvalue? Is the projector still the zero projector?
2. What is the interpretation of $\chi_\Omega$ for general Borel sets $\Omega$ (that is, when $\Omega$ is not necessarily a singleton)? Is this the projection onto the union (or direct sum?) of all eigenspaces such that for each eigenspace its corresponding eigenvalue is in $\Omega$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes. If $\chi_{\{\lambda\}}(A)\ne0$, then any vector in the range of $\chi_{\{\lambda\}}(A)$ is an eigenvector for $\lambda$.
2. An operator may have no eigenvalues. If all the elements of $\Omega$ happen to be eigenvalues, then indeed $\chi_\Omega(A)$ is the projection onto the closure of the linear span of the union of the eigenspaces.

---

**Edit: an example.** Let $H=\mathbb C\oplus L^2[0,1]$. Let
$$
A=2\oplus M_g,
$$
where $g(t)=t\,1_{[1,3]}(t)$ and $M_g$ is the multiplication operator. Then
$$
\chi_{\{\frac12\}}(A)=1\oplus0,\qquad\text{ while }\qquad \chi_{[1,2]}(A)=1\oplus M_h,
$$
with $h=1_{[1,3]}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What if some of the elements in $\Omega$ are eigenvalues but others are not? If $\Omega_\lambda$ is the set of all eigenvalues of $A$ in $\Omega$, then I assume $\chi_\Omega(A) = \chi_{\Omega_\lambda}(A)$? Or put differently, $\chi_{\Omega\setminus\Omega_\lambda}(A) = 0$?

Comment: No, not at all. Let $You cannot think of the spectrum of a general operator in terms of eigenvalues. See the edit.

Comment: Sorry I did not fully understand your example. I thought we may think of the spectrum of a general operator as a disjoint union of the point spectrum (the eigenvalues) and the residual spectrum?

Comment: No, that's not true at all. Multiplication operators by continuous functions which are not constant anywhere are selfadjoint, so their residual spectrum is empty; but they have no eigenvalues. The operator $M_g$ in my answer is an example of that. The spectrum is $[1,3]$, and both the point spectrum and the residual spectrum are empty.

Comment: I think I see the issue. I should have specified that the operator $A$ is assumed to be linear as I have not yet learned about nonlinear operators. On Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decomposition_of_spectrum_(functional_analysis)) it says that the spectrum may be decomposed into three disjoint subsets. In the case $A$ is linear, does it now hold that $\chi_{\Omega\setminus\Omega_\lambda}(A) = 0$? If not, what is the interpretation of $\chi_\Omega(A)$ when $\Omega$ contains both eigenvalues points and non-eigenvalue points?

Comment: No, I was always talking about bounded linear operators, and my examples are such.

Comment: Sorry for all the follow up questions, you have made me realize that I do not understand the spectrum as well as I had thought. So in general, the spectrum cannot be written as a disjoint union of the point spectrum/eigenvalues, the continuous spectrum, and the residual spectrum?

Comment: Yes, you can. But I'm not sure what conclusion you want to draw from that.

Comment: Does this decomposition have any role in the projectors $\chi_\Omega(A)$? My initial understanding was this was a projection onto the eigenspaces associated to the point spectrum within $\Omega$ but as you said this is wrong. My goal is to understand what $\chi_\Omega(A)$ is projecting onto for general Borel subsets $\Omega$.

Comment: Not really. For starters, if $A$ is normal (in particular, selfadjoint) then the residual spectrum is empty. So all you can say is that the continuous spectrum consists of those approximate eigenvalues which are not eigenvalues. But these could be "mingled", i.e. you could have an eigenvalue as a limit of approximate eigenvalues, and vice versa. Meanwhile, the spectral projection only sees closed sets. And in general neither $\sigma_p(A)$ nor $\sigma_c(A)$ are closed.

Comment: Thank you, I am beginning to understand what was wrong about my post now. So the operator $\chi_\Omega(A)$ projects on eigenspaces corresponding to both eigenvalues and approximate eigenvalues that lie in $\Omega$?

Comment: More or less. You cannot really say what an "eigenspsce" is for an approximate eigenvalue.

Comment: Thank you for all your help, I think I finally understand. Do you have any references you can recommend if I wanted to learn more about this point of view for spectral projectors? I have been using Reed & Simon which has been good but they do not go into much detail about approximate eigenvalues and eigenvectors, which seems to be what I need.

Comment: I think it's better to think purely in terms of functional calculus. The subspaces are not really relevant. There are many many books. One you could try is Conway's *A Course in Functional Analysis*

Comment: What was bothering me was finding out what $\chi_\Omega(A)$ was projecting onto exactly so that I could better understand spectral operator-valued integrals. But now that I understand this I will only focus on the functional calculus point of view. Thanks again for all your help and patience, it was very helpful!